# Correct architecture for SPA and routing with multiple components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to Web development as well as to Angular. I need to develop single page application which should have the following "pages":
1. Login page
2. Home page

Home page should contain several sections: 
Reports, Clients, etc.
Additionally, each sections has its own functionality (specific buttons, tables and so on).

I do know the routing basics and have already made login page with the "sign in" button which redirects you to the home page. So, login page is an independent component with its own route.

Now I need to implement the Home page. I decided that it should have always opened navigation tab on the left side (just like there https://material.angular.io/components/categories) and on the remaining part of the screen the specific content of the chosen section should be displayed.

The question is how should I arrange all of this in terms of modules and components to make it more clean and reusable? Also, how do I implement changing of displayable components for each selected section in navigation menu? Should I use routing (if so, some example would be appreciated) or it is possible to use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my projects, and as I see in a number of projects/advice from people, group by use. For example, any feature module is a folder unto itself, with subfolders grouping components. For services that are used within a module on it's own, based on how many, I either put them at the same level as the feature module or in a 'shared' folder. At the app level, I have a shared folder that contains anything that crosses between modules.

If you don't use the Angular CLI yet, do so, as it helps you develop, and more so, it's generators really help drive in a common structure.

As for how you change your menu, that's a entirely different and much bigger question. Depending on your setup, hard code it into your menu or create a service that controls your menu.

Comment: Thanks, angular cli seems to be useful tool!

Answer (score 0):

File arrangement can be user specific. Myself for instance, methods &services that'll be reused such as authentication (login & register), guards stay together. While methods specific to a component could be in the component's folder.